# is there a way to adjust combo list width dynamically in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to adjust combo list width based on list content maximum width.
what are all the possible ways to increase/decrease width of combo list dynamically depends upon on the list items maximum width.

Comment: What API/SDK/framework are you using? MFC, QT, winforms?

Comment: using mfc framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this:

```
void SetBestDroppedWidth(CComboBox *pComboBox)
{
    // Find the longest string in the combo box.
    CString     str;
    CSize       sz;
    int         dx = 0;
    TEXTMETRIC  tm;
    CDC*        pDC = pComboBox->GetDC();
    CFont*      pFont = pComboBox->GetFont();

    // Select the listbox font, save the old font
    CFont* pOldFont = pDC->SelectObject(pFont);
    // Get the text metrics for avg char width
    pDC->GetTextMetrics(&tm);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < pComboBox->GetCount(); i++)
    {
        pComboBox->GetLBText(i, str);
        sz = pDC->GetTextExtent(str);

        // Add the avg width to prevent clipping
        sz.cx += tm.tmAveCharWidth;

        if (sz.cx > dx)
            dx = sz.cx;
    }
    // Select the old font back into the DC
    pDC->SelectObject(pOldFont);
    pComboBox->ReleaseDC(pDC);
    
    // Adjust the width for the vertical scroll bar and the left and right border.
    dx += ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL) + 2 * ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXEDGE);
    
    // If the width of the list box is too small, adjust it so that every
    // item is completely visible.
    if (pComboBox->GetDroppedWidth() < dx)
    {
        pComboBox->SetDroppedWidth(dx);
        ASSERT(pComboBox->GetDroppedWidth() == dx);
    }
}
```

Call it efter all the items have been added to the combobox:

```
//CComboBox         m_HavingRole; // in header file

   for (RoleList::iterator it = rolesObList.begin(); it != rolesObList.end(); it++)
    {
        nItem = m_HavingRole.AddString(it->m_szName);
        m_HavingRole.SetItemData(nItem, it->m_lRoleID);
    }
    SetBestDroppedWidth(&m_HavingRole);
```

Comment: Thanks - Lucian.

Comment: That looks pretty good. But you would have to explain *WHY* there might be clipping and how do you know that adding `tm.tmAveCharWidth` is enough?